# Core Data one-to-many relation won't take values, how do I have do use the accessor methods?

Tags: ios, xcode, core-data, one-to-many, relation

I want to save a method, which has some relations to other Entities. The approach and background are to-one relations, but the method should have be able to have several tipps and examples. I already looked at many other questions and tutorials but I do not know why it won't work. 
dataToBeSaved is a Dictionary containing the data as Strings I want to assign to the method.

**Here is Method.h**

```
@interface Method : NSManagedObject

@property (nonatomic, retain) NSNumber * id;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSString * name;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Approach *methodtoapproach;
@property (nonatomic, retain) Background *methodtobackground;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *methodtoexample;
@property (nonatomic, retain) NSSet *methodtotipps;
@end

@interface Method (CoreDataGeneratedAccessors)

- (void)addMethodtoexampleObject:(Example *)value;
- (void)removeMethodtoexampleObject:(Example *)value;
- (void)addMethodtoexample:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMethodtoexample:(NSSet *)values;

- (void)addMethodtotippsObject:(Tipps *)value;
- (void)removeMethodtotippsObject:(Tipps *)value;
- (void)addMethodtotipps:(NSSet *)values;
- (void)removeMethodtotipps:(NSSet *)values;

@end
```

**and here is my code, I let the commented sections in it, so you can see what I tried to to...**

```
Method *newMethod = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Method" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];

//    [newMethod setValue:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"name"] forKey:@"name"];
//    [newMethod setValue:[NSNumber numberWithInt:11] forKey:@"id"];
    newMethod.name = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"name"];
    newMethod.id = [NSNumber numberWithInt:11];
    newMethod.methodtoapproach.summary = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"summary"];
    newMethod.methodtobackground.background = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"background"];



    NSMutableSet *tippsSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"tipps"], nil];
    NSMutableSet *exampleSet = [[NSMutableSet alloc] initWithObjects:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"example"], nil];

    [newMethod addMethodtotipps:tippsSet];
    [newMethod addMethodtoexample:exampleSet];
//    [[newMethod mutableSetValueForKey:@"methodtotipps"] addObject:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"tipps"]];
//    [[newMethod mutableSetValueForKey:@"methodtoexample"] addObject:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"example"]];
//    [newMethod addMethodtotippsObject:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"tipps"]];
//    [newMethod addMethodtoexampleObject:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"example"]];
//    newMethod.methodtotipps.tipps = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"tipps"];
//    newMethod.methodtoexample.example = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"example"];
```

if I run the app exactly like that, I get the error:

> *** Terminating app due to uncaught exception 'NSInvalidArgumentException', reason: '-[__NSCFString entity]: unrecognized selector sent to instance xxx

if you need more information, just post it in the comments...

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Actually, it now worked for me like this:#

```
AppDelegate *appDelegate = [[UIApplication sharedApplication] delegate];

managedObjectContext = [appDelegate managedObjectContext];
fetchedResultsController = [appDelegate fetchedResultsController];
Method *newMethod = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Method" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Approach *newApproach = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Approach" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Background *newBackground = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Background" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Tipps *newtipp = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Tipps" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];
Example *newExample = [NSEntityDescription insertNewObjectForEntityForName:@"Example" inManagedObjectContext:managedObjectContext];


[newMethod setName:[dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"name"]];
[newMethod setId:[NSNumber numberWithInt:11]];
newApproach.summary = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"summary"];
newBackground.background = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"background"];
newtipp.tipps = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"tipps"];
newExample.example = [dataToBeSaved objectForKey:@"example"];

NSMutableSet *tippsSet = [NSMutableSet set];
NSMutableSet *examplesSet = [NSMutableSet set];

[newMethod setMethodtoapproach:newApproach];
[newMethod setMethodtobackground:newBackground];
[newMethod setMethodtoexample:examplesSet];
[newMethod setMethodtotipps:tippsSet];

[newMethod addMethodtoexampleObject:newExample];
[newMethod addMethodtotippsObject:newtipp];

NSError *error;
if (managedObjectContext != nil)
{
    if([managedObjectContext hasChanges])
    {
        [managedObjectContext save:&error];
        if(error)
        {
            NSLog(@"Error Saving data: %@", [error userInfo]);
        }
    }
}
```

might be just what @Fogmeister meant but I'm (up till now) fine with how it works. Maybe later there is some optimization necessary... I'll post it here if so...

Answer (score 0):

Yeah, I was caught out by this also.

If you want to use the methods...

```
- (void)add<blah>Object...
```

Then you need to write it yourself.

What I actually do is create the relationship the other way around.

instead of creating the child and then adding the child to the parent. I create the child and then tell the child what its parent is.

Comment: I thought about your answer, but I think I solved it the other way round anyway. Just hope that it'll work on the rest of the app too..

Comment: It should work either way. Mine is just another option :) hope you got it sorted.